# SQL decimal(18,4) round whole numbers?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm wondering how whole numbers can be rounded.

For example I have values entered like this: `500`

but after I query the data value is returned like this: `500.00`.

Is there a way to round whole numbers but at the same time leave decimal numbers like this: `9.45`?

I use SQL Server 2008 Management Studio. If anyone can help please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: Where are the numbers being presented to the user? You should do it there.

Comment: I present them in HTML table. So you are suggesting doing this in JavaScript?

Comment: As Martin alludes to, this is a display issue, not a SQL issue. The data is what it is. How you display it is up to the front end.

Comment: You can do it in SQL (although I tend to agree, the web is proably a better layer). You can use the `ROUND()` function, or depending on if you just want it truncated as opposed to rounded, you could cast it as an `int` or `decimal(18,0)`

Comment: @Xedni - you can't do it in SQL and have different scale and precision for the same column across rows unless you convert it to string or sql variant.

Comment: @MartinSmith you're correct. Sorry if I wasn't clear or i misunderstood. If that's the primary concern, then yeah, definitely do that in the display layer. It's worth noting, floats will sometimes (always?) do that, where 5.00 will be truncated, but others will not. However that opens up a different can of worms

Comment: Actually, you could use FLOAT or REAL... They will not display a decimal if there is nothing behind the decimal. Of course there are accuracy issues that can make FLOAT & REAL less than ideal when precision is required.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not asking to round the numbers, for you don't want to alter the actual value. Instead, what you are asking is a formatting issue. Most of the time, this should be done in the presentation layer and not in SQL server.

Formatting a value is the act of creating a textual representation (string) of this value, often based on some given format specifiers and a locale (the locale will often be the default locale when omitted).

Since you are using SQL Server, I assume that you are using a .NET language. Most numeric types in .NET support an overload of the method `ToString()` that accepts custom format options. See the [MSDN documentation on custom format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings).

If you really do want to format the numeric value in SQL Server, then SQL Server 2012 and up has the `Format()` function. Unfortunately, this function is not yet available in SQL Server 2008. This `Format()` function is very similar to the .NET version.

For example, the following code will format the numbers in the format that you wish:

```
PRINT FORMAT(500.00, '#.##') -- prints "500"
PRINT FORMAT(9.45, '#.##') -- prints "9.45"
```

Note that this will always round to at most 2 decimals. If you want more decimals, then you could increase the number of `#` after the dot.

Answer (score 0):

try this query:  (where value is the column)

```
use your_database;

select 
   Cast(CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2),value) as nvarchar) AS Value2 
FROM 
   table_name;
```